# If condition is True, output a txt file to directory path with a message

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I am looking to output a text file with a certain message to a directory path if the below results is a 'True'.

```
df['Fraud Account'].isnull().values.any()
```

Is there a way to do this in Jupyter notebook?

Thank you!

Comment: Where are you stuck?! The "if True" part? The file part? The message part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but reading literally your question I think the answer would be sth like that:

```
if df['Fraud Account'].isnull().values.any():
    open("my_file.txt", "wt").write("My message")
```

Contents of file would be replaced. If you wanted to append, you just replace `wt` by `at` in second parameter.

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I was after. Apologies if my question was a bit vague, I'm fairly new to python. This helps a lot!